# Execute a method once before testing starts for several features and scenarios

Tags: java, selenium, frameworks, cucumber, pageobjects

In our web application, logging into a certain page requires ages. Our features and scenario sets are written from that particular page. We do not have any validations before that page. Takes about 10 minutes just to reach that page.

Before I explain further. This is in Cucumber and we are using Selenium with Java.

So the login action should be done and that webdriver session should stay intact and then the scenario validations start. The Features below has the below scenarios. Each subsequent scenario is dependent on the previous one. Meaning, these scenarios need to be executed sequentially.

1st Feature should execute the scenarios sequentially. 
Then the 2nd Feature should execute the scenarios sequentially. 
In between I don't want a new session created for the 2nd scenario. 
These are all dependent sequentially.

How can I implement this?

```
Feature: Add a product to the quote

    So that the quotation can be built on the added product

    Scenario: Add a Hub
        Given User A has logged in
        Then Add button is available
        Then Add Hub
        Then Enter correct Address details
        Then select correct bandwidth
        And Save to Quote

    Scenario: Add a Spoke
        Given User A has logged in
        Then Add button is available
        Then Add Spoke
        Then Enter correct Address details
        Then select correct bandwidth
        And Save to Quote


Feature: Give discount to the quote for Hub

    So that the quotation can be sent to the customer

    Scenario: Give 10% discount 
        Given Hub has already been added
        Then Go to the Quote Tab
        Then Enter the discount
        Then Save the Quote
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sequential Running of features** - Two ways of doing this. First one, depend on the fact that cucumber runs features in **alphabetic** order. So name them accordingly. But this approach is easily broken by a new feature file name which slots in between the ones you created earlier. Second, specify the running order in the cucumberoptions feature value eg `features = "second.feature,first.feature"` in the runner file. This will run the second.feature first. Refer to [this](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/specify-execution-order-of-cucumber-features/) for more details.

**Keeping driver alive across feature files** - Use the concept of a [SharedWebDriver](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets/SharedDriver.java) which has a static `WebDriver` inside it and a JVM shutdown hook which closes the driver at the end. Though you might need to add appropriate before and after hooks to cleanup cookies etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your web application so that login does not take ages, rather than make your Cukes totally unreliable by trying to preserve a session between scenarios. Sometimes your tests give you feedback which should act upon rather than work around ;)

As login is a completely trivial thing 99.999% of web applications do quickly and effectively I find it hard to believe that your application is so special that you can't do this. If you can't then perhaps you should create a new question explaining why your login is so slow and find some solutions

Sharing on session between scenarios means that none of your Cukes that share the session can do anything that changes any data without making your scenarios unreliable. This means that any interactions that result in POST rather than a GET should not be allowed. So no form filling, submitting forms etc. etc.

You can of course work around this, but it will create serious problems which will only show up quite a bit later. Then when scenarios start failing it will take you 10 times as long to work out why they are failing because you will have to understand the whole chain of connected scenarios.